# working with timestamps and time zones

Tags: php, mysql, time

From my android smartphone application (made by myself) I send a request to a server in Denver to save my location and time. The `TIMESTAMP` it saves is Denver's current time (9 hours difference from local time). Now after 16 hours from the last request I wrote in my php script

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblLoc` WHERE datetime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 86400)";
```

so as if I wanted to show me past 24 hours....

THIS WAS MISTAKE!

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tblLoc` WHERE datetime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR";
```

in SQL 86400 != 24 HOUR!!!

Comment: Can you add the query you use to insert or update table tblLoc?

Comment: Please try to boil your question down to its essence; is there any way you can make your description of the problem **shorter** and **clearer**?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear. His server is in Denver time, but he needs it to be in Asia/Jerusalem time. He isn't getting the results he is expecting because of this. Perhaps the question is a bit long-winded, but I think the problem is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change [MySQL's time zone](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) instead of PHP's, or change your query so that PHP provides the timestamp, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblLoc WHERE dateTime > (". time() ." - 86400)";
```

---

**EDIT** based on comment

`UTC_TIMESTAMP()` might be a good way to go, but make sure you are inserting/updating based on this same timestamp as well, and not based on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

UTC timestamp is based on GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) and is at GMT+0. Dallas is at GMT-6 and Asia/Jerusalem is at GMT+2. So `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` always means the current time in GMT timezone, regardless of what your current time zone setting is. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` means the current time in your current timezone.

**HOWEVER** your results may still not be quite right. They may just look right for the moment, but may be off by a couple hours. But if you are inserting and updating based on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and then selecting based on `UTC_TIMESTAMP` your results will not be correct.

I would suggest one of the following three solutions:

1. Switch your server's timezone to Asia/Jerusalem (make sure to restart MySQL to apply the change).
2. Set the timezone at the beginning of each script using 'SET time_zone = timezone;'.
3. Make a `TZ` environment variable with the correct timezone so that MySQL sets that timezone as the default on startup (again, make sure to restart MySQL).

Comment: @qpaycm: See updated answer. Also, if my answer was the solution to your problem, please mark it as your accepted answer using the check mark under the voting buttons for this post.

Comment: @qpaycm: My fault, didn't realize that. See updated answer again.

Comment: strange :) I just tried DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) work perfect! it seems that 86400!=1day - this was the problem